# How do I publish all pages on google sites

Tags: google-sites

When I publish my google site it only seems to publish the home pages,,any subpages will not allow me to click further.

What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications SE. Please take the [Tour] and review [ask]. Then [edit] your question to include additional details. For example, have you followed the [instructions to publish a page](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/98216)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.